# Integration testing ASP.NET Core with identity. Best practice to add testusers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing

I have an ASP.NET Core application.

I want to create some integration tests for the API endpoints. I use testContainers to create a database.

And I extend the `WebApplicationFactory` to change the `dbContext` (so that it uses my new database).

Now some endpoints retrieve all the documents for the authenticated user.

But because it is a fresh test database I obviously do not have any user.

I now need to add some user with which I can make the API calls.

I see 3 possible solutions:

1. Use EF Core and seed some data.
   Drawback: because it is user data I need to consider the hashing of the password etc.
   Benefit: straight forward
2. Using the `webApplicationFactory` get the `userManager` of ASP.NET Core Identity (which I use in my application) and persist it using that.
   Benefit: I do not have to worry about all the small things like encrypting the password
   Drawback: I need to get the userManager first
3. Use my API `/register`
   Benefit: everything will be handled for me. I do not have to worry that I have forgotten anything.
   Drawback: if my `/register` API does not work everything breaks.

What should I use? Is there another option? Is there some established best practice?

I think I am currently preferring option #3. Because it seems to be the simplest and most robust. For example in .NET 8.0, I think there will no longer be a username property. Currently I am copying the email into this field. If this now changes and I do NOT go with option 3 I have to change it in my `/register` endpoint logic AND in my test logic.

Comment: I used to set data seed in ef core, But call `/register` api is also a good method. the choice depends on your specific testing goals and how closely you want your tests to resemble real-world scenarios

Comment: What about the role? How can a user role be handled? What I mean is that my controllers are available for certain roles, such as administrator. I register a user, but that user has no role. Should I register the user, retrieve that user's ID from the database, and assign the role "Admin" to that ID?